# WCF REST: Encrypting credentials when using my own custom validator - UserNamePasswordValidator?

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-security, wcf-rest

I am using my own custom validator by inheriting from UserNamePasswordValidator. The service is hosted in a windows service. Is there a way to encrypt the username / password and descrypt it on the service?

What are my other options, do i have to create a key combination?

Answer (score 2):

If you have configured your service to use the `UserName` clientCredentialType, your credentials will already be encrypted.

WCF does not allow us to transmit UserName and Password in plain text without extending the framework with your own binding (as is demonstrated on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/ClearUsernameBinding.aspx)).

Comment: This applies to REST as well??

Comment: Ahh ok, yes i see... So i have to use HTTPS or create a certificate?

Comment: @Martin: I'm not a REST expert but REST (in .NET) sits on top of WCF, so I presume it applies.  Yes, you will have to use https *and* create a certificate to use a username/password.